# Loading large dataset using ActiveJDBC

Tags: java, activejdbc

I have a SQL script with Insert statements (around 100 rows and might increase in the future) that I would like to execute using ActiveJDBC.  Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes please see this: http://javalite.io/batch_operations - close to the end of the page. 
We used this to process millions of records from files in batches of 1000 records each

This method presumes that the file has only data, such as CSV file. If you need to execute SQL verbatim, you can use: [Base#exec](http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/org/javalite/activejdbc/Base.html#exec-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Worked very well.  My SQL scripts has `COMMIT` at the end. Would it make any difference if I either keep or remove them?

Comment: depends on how you manage transactions. I'd rather  do it in Java code.